# Spring Apache Kafka decoupled message queue best practice

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi, message-queue, data-stream

I have a problem regrading renewing an old interface of data exporting to a client of ours.
13 years ago,
A queue logic was developed in an Oracle package (Fully SQL code) - the data is inserted into a queue table, and than exported via an IIS server built in C#, which functionality is basic:

- The IIS server is exporting an HTTP get request, which is polled 5 times per second (Which in terms of 13 years ago was online polling).
- Every request removes the first record (FIFO) of the queue table, and sends it to the client.

Today, We have a Spring server which saves the data to the Oracle DB.
When coming to renew this interface, I've encountered issues regarding on how to do it.
My main idea is using **Apache Kafka** which has great connection to Spring & some good documentation, In order to achieve this online message queue.
My main problem is the high coupling the consumer needs to have - From what I understood this far, the consumer needs to develop an architecture built **specifically** for the Kafka client, which is something I want to prevent - I want to build a service layer on our side which will export the Kafka message queue.
I've also thought about using **Apache NiFi** for this and managing a queue there.

Comment: Yes, using Kafka requires having a Kafka client, just like using Oracle requires a certain database driver and SQL syntax... I wouldn't necessarily consider that as coupling. What exactly is the question? You can use tools like Golden Gate or Debezium to get data from Oracle to Kafka directly, and Spring Cloud Streams has abstract bindings to consume from any message queue such as Kafka

Comment: Requirement of apache client is not coupling, as mention above you would always need some sort of client/driver to access the information stored in database or messaging platform.  you can also explore to remove oracle if purpose is  message sharing, client can directly publish message to Kafka and consumer will pull the message. Please note "Pull", you can't avoid Pull. Obviously Kafka has much more feature than just messaging platform.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for your answers! As I mentioned, in the previous architecture we had, we exported a Restful API which they made requests to. That way, we prevented coupling - the service was handling the DB, and no matter what the DB was, they would always make the same requests to the API. What does interest me is the Spring Cloud Streams you mentioned as the abstraction is clearly a better idea on their side.

Comment: You can still put a Kafka client behind an HTTP service. Even Nifi can be used to combine ListenHTTP with ProduceKafka processors